# Is there a Football (soccer) Manager Open Source in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Does anybody knows of a open source football manager lib written in Ruby?

I am writing one would like to have some base to match against, any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick search on GitHub revealed these:

- [champz](https://github.com/kinfante/champz) - Championship management. Seems pretty active.
- [rojos_soccer](https://github.com/gusortiz/rojos_soccer) - Team management. Rather old, last commit was near the beggining of 2009.
- [Solebury-Soccer](https://github.com/seandevs/Solebury-Soccer) - Practice log tracker, if I understood right. Looks pretty old too.

It seems `champz`'s your best shot.

Comment: +1 Ok! He is really doing some work there. I will just keep the question open some more.

Answer (score 1):

Most recente GitHub search, revealed one more:

- http://github.com/paliyoes/pfc_sfo_rails3

I've found a installed version here:

http://pfc-sfo-rails3.herokuapp.com